# Is it possible to host django website in the github?

Tags: django, github, templates, web, hosting

i want to try django website to host in github. is it possible to host it?

try it. try it, try it. still now i try it last 3 Days.

what should i do for this. any other solution is there. any one reply me with right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking if its possible to host your django web application on Github Pages.

It is not possible. Github pages is made for hosting static website, whereas Django project needs Python and many other libraries to dynamically generate/render the html pages.

You can try looking at free tier alternatives such as Heroku, PythonAnywhere, etc

Comment: can we use django-distill -> https://django-distill.com/  for this?

Comment: Yes you can, but it may not support all use cases.